# HsqlDB: Reloading server.properties

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

I have an HsqlDB server running, and I need to add db aliases on the fly to the server.properties file, without restarting the db server. Is it possible? Or do I need to shutdown and restart the whole HsqlDB server?

The situation is that I have a single HsqlDB server with many databases, and many Java web applications, each of them using its own database. By now, I can't create new instances of the web application without restarting the whole HsqlDB server.

I tried to use the following JDBC urls:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost;file:/srv/databases/db1
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost;file:/srv/databases/db2
etc...
```

But in this case all the webapps connect to the same database (that is the first one connected to). I'd like to use in the apps:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db1
jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/db2
```

I found no mentions of these "problems" in the documentations.
Where am I doing wrong?

Thank-you

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the server with the server.remote_open=true property. After that, the URL needs to be included as well as the file path.

It is explained in the Guide with an example:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_remote_open

Comment: Thank-you. But actually I did. My server.properties file begins with server.remote_open=true. In fact, I can remotely open a database, but when I try to remotely open a second database, I obtain a connection to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: if I connect using the following URLS:

`jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/databasea;file:/srv/databases/databasea`

and

`jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/databaseb;file:/srv/databases/databaseb`

then the two connections actually connect to the two databases.
My problem was that I used the same alias (//localhost) for both.
Now I do not need aliases in the server.properties file.